# How can i use href link in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I'm simple programmer so please be patient with me
i coding a new website but i have some issues and i hope you will helps me

I want to link my page in button by php but with a condition

the condition : if the `$_SESSION ['use'] = $username` i want to show Logout button but if the `$_SESSION ['use'] = NULL` i want to show Login button,

```
  <?php
     session_start();
     $username = $_POST ['uname'];
     $password = $_POST ['pass'];

     if ($_SESSION['use'] = $username) 
     {
     echo '<a href="http://localhost/project/LogoutPage.html" > Logout </a>';
     } 
     if ($_SESSION['use'] = NULL) 
     {
     echo '<a href="http://localhost/project/LoginIndex.html" > Login </a>';
     }
  ?>
```

this the output:

```
Logout '; } if ($_SESSION['use'] = NULL) { echo ' Login '; } ?>
```

Comment: You have not set the session variable, so this will not work.

Comment: to compare `$_SESSION['use']` against `$username` you need to use `==` not `=`. it should be: `if ($_SESSION['use'] == $username)`